# NgRX reducer is returning undefined value

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm trying to get my Angular application to play nice with the NgRX store but I'm having some issues:

```
// app.module.ts

import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { fileReducer }  from './state/file-state/file-state.reducer'

  imports: [
    ...
    StoreModule.forRoot({
      fileReducer
    })
  ],
```

```
// file-state.actions.ts

import { createAction, props } from "@ngrx/store";

export const getReceipts = createAction('[Receipt] Get receipt')
```

```
// file-state.reducer.ts

import { createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as ReceiptActions from './file-state.actions';

const initialState: Receipt = {
  merchant_name: 'default'
}

export const fileReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(ReceiptActions.getReceipts, state => (initialState))
)
```

And finally my component:

```
// view-files.component.ts

import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { getReceipts } from 'src/app/state/file-state/file-state.actions';

  constructor(private store: Store) {
    console.log(this.store.dispatch(getReceipts()))
  }
```

The console.log shows a `undefined`, where I would expect an object with a `merchant_name: 'default'`.

Comment: do you expect the dispatch method to return value?

Comment: @Alexy yes. I thought the dispatch method would call `getReceipts` action which would trigger the reducer to return the initial state.

Comment: it doesn't return a value, it is an void method and it will return undefined. You need a `selectors` to take a value from store

https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors

Comment: So an action will never return a value? A reducer will transform the data which needs to be returned through a selector?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. Take a look at the diagram, it shows the life cycle ngrx state manager. https://ngrx.io/guide/store#diagram

Answer (score 0):

The `dispatch` method doesn't return the state (its return type is `void`).
It just sends the action to all registered reducers and effects.

To read the state, you can use `store.select()` in combination with selectors.
Keep in mind that reading the state isn't synchronous, but it's an Observable stream.